# Why do some Unicode characters appear as boxes?

Tags: character-encoding, unicode, utf-8

Some Unicode characters cannot be shown in my browser.

I generated valid Unicode (utf8) characters but many of them are unable to be displayed. If they don't have representation, then why are they exist and how can I fix this?
Thanks.

[image: Unicode characters]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no glyphs available. Your display engine (browser) indicates this by displaying the hex number of the UTF-8 character. It uses the box to indicate this behavior. Your characters have been probably encoded incorrectly.

*Edit*:

Corresponding to [utf-8 icons](http://www.utf8icons.com/) the character 0x0E5C belongs to the Thai subset of UTF-8. But there is no name for [that character](http://www.utf8icons.com/character/3676/UTF-8-character) while the previous is named [KHOMUT](http://www.utf8icons.com/character/3675/UTF-8-character). So you used a reserved but not used character.

Additionally you need a font that includes the glyphs for the character. Since 05EC doesn't have a name at [utf-8 icons](http://www.utf8icons.com/) it's possible that it is not included in your font.

Comment: yes but i don't think it's a problem of my browser because i'm not using something special.. I mean it's been displayed like this in the most known browsers. Can i fix the encoding or there is something i can do or if you know any reference on the subject?

Comment: @JorgeCode it's the font that is the problem. If you change the font your browser uses to one that has the appropriate glyphs they will appear.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, a box containing a four-digit hex number is a common way of indicating lack of glyph for a character in the font(s) being used. But in this case, the data apparently contains code points that have not (yet) been assigned to characters at all, so fonts *should not* have any glyphs for them.

For example, the first problem case here has 0E5C in the box, so it indicates U+05EC, which is a reserved (unassigned) code point in Unicode at present. This means that it does not denote any character data and should not be used in a character string.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it the following way. I have this text: ['','','',''].

For me it looks like this:
[image].
I went to [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/) and click "Filter" button.
You will see a "Preview" textbox. I copied and pasted my text there.
[image].
Then you can see how this text will be displayed by different fonts. Some of them will contain the same boxes. But some will show actual characters.
I scrolled it down and finally found one which can display this.
It was "Noto Sans Symbols 2". It shows it like this:
[image].
I installed this font and the problem was fixed!